# NSXMLParser iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When exactly does the delegate method in iPhone SDK gets called
parser:didEndElement:...

Even though it says it gets called whenever NSXMLParser reaches the end of an element

Say we have an XML;

1
2
3

I am a bit unclear what exactly does "end of an element" mean ? Does it mean at the end of every element in the XML..So in the above example, will these method be called 4 times (once for  and 3 times for the )

Also is these the main delegate method where majority of parsing takes place and not the other 2 methods;
parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement
parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gets called when it finishes parsing an element (that is it reaches a closing tag). For example, given the following XML:

```
<person>
  <name>Kevin</name>
</person>
```

It will be called when the parser reaches `</name>` and `</person>`.

Typically you are required to use a combination of the methods and no *main* delegate method exists. Usually you will start construction of an object on `didStartElement`, modify the data on `foundCharacters` and finalize or setup complex data structures in `didFinishElement`. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is fairly clear for this.